# Is there a way to cumulatively and distinctively expand list in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science, python-polars, rust-polars

For distance, I want to accomplish conversion like below.

```
┌────────────┐
│ col        │
│ ---        │
│ list[str]  │
╞════════════╡
│ ["a"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["a", "b"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["c"]      │
└────────────┘
↓
↓
↓
┌────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ col        ┆ col_cum         │
│ ---        ┆ ---             │
│ list[str]  ┆ list[str]       │
╞════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ ["a"]      ┆ ["a"]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["a", "b"] ┆ ["a", "b"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ["c"]      ┆ ["a", "b", "c"] │
└────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I've tried `polars.Expr.cumulative_eval()`, but not work.
From the [Offical API](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.cumulative_eval.html?highlight=cumulative_eval) example. I can access the first element and last element in every iteration. But I want here is the result of the previous iteration i think.
Could I get some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `cumulative_eval` expression.

But first, let's expand your data so that we can include some other things that may be of interest.

- We'll include a `group` variable to show how the algorithm can be used with grouping variables.
- We'll also include an empty list to show how the algorithm will handle these.

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "group": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
        "var": [["a"], ["a", "b"], ["c"], ["p"], ["q", "p"], [], ["s"]],
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (7, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ var        │
│ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["a"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["a", "b"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["c"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["p"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["q", "p"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ []         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["s"]      │
└───────┴────────────┘
```

#### The Algorithm

Here's the heart of the algorithm:

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('var')
        .cumulative_eval(
            pl.element()
            .explode()
            .unique()
            .sort()
            .list()
        )
        .over('group')
        .alias('cumulative')
    )
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ var        ┆ cumulative           │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---                  │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[str]            │
╞═══════╪════════════╪══════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["a"]      ┆ ["a"]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["a", "b"] ┆ ["a", "b"]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["c"]      ┆ ["a", "b", "c"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["p"]      ┆ ["p"]                │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["q", "p"] ┆ ["p", "q"]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ []         ┆ [null, "p", "q"]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["s"]      ┆ [null, "p", ... "s"] │
└───────┴────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

Notice the `null` introduced by the empty list.  If you want, you can eliminate this with a filtering step.

```py
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('var')
        .cumulative_eval(
            pl.element()
            .explode()
            .unique()
            .sort()
            .list()
        )
        .over('group')
        .alias('cumulative')
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col('cumulative').arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_not_null())
        )
    )
)
```

```
shape: (7, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ group ┆ var        ┆ cumulative      │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---             │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[str]       │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["a"]      ┆ ["a"]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["a", "b"] ┆ ["a", "b"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["c"]      ┆ ["a", "b", "c"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["p"]      ┆ ["p"]           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["q", "p"] ┆ ["p", "q"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ []         ┆ ["p", "q"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2     ┆ ["s"]      ┆ ["p", "q", "s"] │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

#### How it works

`cumulative_eval` allows us to treat a subset of rows for a column as if it was a Series itself (with the exception that we access the elements of the underlying Series using `polars.element`.)

So, let's simulate what the `cumulative_eval` expression is doing by working work with the Series itself directly.  We'll simulate what the algorithm does when `cumulative_eval` reaches the last row where `group ==  1` (the third row).

The first major step of the algorithm is to [`explode`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Expr.explode.html) the lists.  `explode` will put each element of each list on its own row:

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col('var')
        .filter(pl.col('group') == 1)
        .explode()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌─────┐
│ var │
│ --- │
│ str │
╞═════╡
│ a   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ a   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   │
└─────┘
```

In the next step, we will use `unique` and `sort` to eliminate duplicates and keep the order consistent.

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col('var')
        .filter(pl.col('group') == 1)
        .explode()
        .unique()
        .sort()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────┐
│ var │
│ --- │
│ str │
╞═════╡
│ a   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ b   │
├╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ c   │
└─────┘
```

At this point, we need only to roll up all the values into a list.

```py
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col('var')
        .filter(pl.col('group') == 1)
        .explode()
        .unique()
        .sort()
        .list()
    )
)
```

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ var             │
│ ---             │
│ list[str]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ ["a", "b", "c"] │
└─────────────────┘
```

And that is the value that `cumulative_eval` returns for the third row.

#### Performance

The documentation for `cumulative_eval` comes with a strong warning about performance.

> Warning: This can be really slow as it can have O(n^2) complexity. Don’t use this for operations that visit all elements.

Let's simulate some data.  The code below generates about 9.5 million records, 10,000 groups, so that there are about 950 observations per group.

```py
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

rng = np.random.default_rng(1)

nbr_rows = 10_000_000
df = (
    pl.DataFrame({
        'group': rng.integers(1, 10_000, size=nbr_rows),
        'sub_list': rng.integers(1, 10_000, size=nbr_rows),
        'var': rng.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), nbr_rows)
    })
    .groupby(['group', 'sub_list'])
    .agg(
        pl.col('var')
    )
    .drop('sub_list')
    .sort('group')
)
df
```

```
shape: (9515737, 2)
┌───────┬────────────┐
│ group ┆ var        │
│ ---   ┆ ---        │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]  │
╞═══════╪════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["q", "r"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["z"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["b"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["j"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...   ┆ ...        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["z"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["e"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["s"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["s"]      │
└───────┴────────────┘
```

One my 32-core system, here's the wall-clock time:

```py
import time
start = time.perf_counter()
(
    df
    .with_column(
        pl.col('var')
        .cumulative_eval(
            pl.element()
            .explode()
            .unique()
            .sort()
            .list()
        )
        .over('group')
        .alias('cumulative')
    )
    .with_column(
        pl.col('cumulative').arr.eval(
            pl.element().filter(pl.element().is_not_null())
        )
    )
)
print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

```
shape: (9515737, 3)
┌───────┬────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ group ┆ var        ┆ cumulative          │
│ ---   ┆ ---        ┆ ---                 │
│ i64   ┆ list[str]  ┆ list[str]           │
╞═══════╪════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 1     ┆ ["q", "r"] ┆ ["q", "r"]          │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["z"]      ┆ ["q", "r", "z"]     │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["b"]      ┆ ["b", "q", ... "z"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1     ┆ ["j"]      ┆ ["b", "j", ... "z"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...   ┆ ...        ┆ ...                 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["z"]      ┆ ["a", "b", ... "z"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["e"]      ┆ ["a", "b", ... "z"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["s"]      ┆ ["a", "b", ... "z"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 9999  ┆ ["s"]      ┆ ["a", "b", ... "z"] │
└───────┴────────────┴─────────────────────┘
>>> print(time.perf_counter() - start)
118.46121257600134
```

Roughly 2 minutes on my system for 9.5 million records.  Depending on your system, you may get better or worse performance.  But the point is that is didn't take **hours** to complete.

If you need better performance, we can come up with a better-performing algorithm (or perhaps put in a feature request for a `cumlist` feature in Polars, which might have a complexity better than the O(n^2) complexity of `cumulative_eval`.)

Comment: Thank you so much! You solved my problem and I learned a lot from your answer!
I'm new to polars, and your answer show me what happened exactly there, it is really helpful. And even the performance explanation! I was also curious about the The documentation's performance warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[['a']], [['a', 'b']], [['c']]], columns=['list'])
df['list_cum'] = df.list.cumsum().apply(set).apply(sorted)
print(df)
```

prints

| index | list | list_cum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | a |
| 1 | a,b | a,b |
| 2 | c | a,b,c |

Comment: This question is about polars, not pandas

Comment: Thank you Sir! I can confirm your solution exactly did what I want by Pandas. But I am still curious about is there a way to do same thing using Polars